# Ranorex Report generation with Debug Level Disabled

Tags: ranorex

Can a Ranorex (version 10.7.6) report be generated with the debug level turned off by default, i.e. all debug messages are hidden?

I still want the messages to be logged and to be able to view them, so setting the minimum level to 'info' is not a viable solution for me.